# How do I print out the contents of a file from a reference parameter? I

Tags: c++

// I am trying to get my program to print out an ID number next to days of absences for each line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int ID_num;
int num_absent;
int Max_ID_num = 9999;
int Min_ID_num = 1;
int Total_absences = 0.0;

double get_total_employees();
int calculate_total_days_absented(ofstream &, int);
ofstream Outputfile;
ifstream Inputfile;
double compute_average_days_absented(double, int);
int main()
{
    
    int num2;
    double num3, num;
    
    num = get_total_employees();
    cout << "The total number of employees at this company are " << num << endl;
    Outputfile.open("NameEmployeeAbsences.txt");
    num2 = calculate_total_days_absented(Outputfile, num);
    
    cout << "The total number of absences for every employee is " << num2 << endl;
    Outputfile.close();
    Inputfile.open("NameEmployeeAbsences.txt");
    if (Inputfile)
    {
        cout << ID_num << num_absent << endl;
        
        
    }

    
    Inputfile.close();
    
    cout << "The average number of absences per employee are " << compute_average_days_absented(num, num2) << endl;

    

    
}


double get_total_employees()
{
        double employees;
        cout << "How many employees work at this company ? ";
        cin >> employees;
        return employees;

}
int calculate_total_days_absented(ofstream& Outputfile, int employees)
{
    
    for (int count = 1;count <= employees; count++)
    {
        
        
        cout << "Employee number " << count << " please enter your ID number:" << endl;
        cin >> ID_num;
        while (ID_num < Min_ID_num || ID_num > Max_ID_num)
        {
            cout << "ID number must be between 1 and 9999. Please enter a valid ID number:" << endl;
            cin >> ID_num;
        }
        cout << "Please enter the amount of days you were absent this year";
        cin >> num_absent;
        Total_absences += num_absent;
        Outputfile << ID_num << "\t\t";
        Outputfile << num_absent << "\n";
    }
        
        
        return Total_absences;
    
}
double compute_average_days_absented(double total_employees, int total_absences)
{
    double num4;
    num4 = total_absences / total_employees;
    return num4;

}
```

I am trying to get my program to print out an ID number next to days of absences for each line. It will give me only the most recent numbers I entered into the file. This system is asking me to enter moore details so I'm just gonna write this

Comment: Create an employee structure. Deserialize the input file into employee structures stored in an array or container class. Count up the total employee absentees by traversing the container of employee structures. Then traverse the the container again and print out each employee's relevant statistics.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment by user4581301.

Basically you need to reorganise/rewrite your code. The way you are trying to do it now just makes things difficult. You need to separate out different pieces of functionality in a more coherent way, so you can put together different functions to do different tasks.

1. Define a structure for your employees

```cpp
     struct Employee {
         int id;
         int num_absent;
     };
```

2. Write a function that asks the user for employee details and returns a array of employees from the data entered.
3. Write a function that writes an array of employees to a file
4. Write a function that reads an array of employees from a file
5. Write a function that iterates through an array of employees and calculates the total absenses.

Do you see where this is going, everything is centered around an array of employees. Every function performs one and only one task. This is much more flexible than the code you have currently.